# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext retina resolutions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
UIImageView *cellimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , 107, 70)];
```

The above statement i am sure will make appropriate sizes in both retina resolution devices and standard ones..that is a frame of 107 x 70 pixels on standard and 214 x 140 on retina.

What i want to know is if the below `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` does the same too.. image will be 67 x 67 for standard and 124 x 124 for retina versions?

```
    CGSize imagesize = CGSizeMake(67, 67);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imagesize);
        NSLog(@" Converting ");
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imagesize.width,imagesize.height)];
        newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

if not can anyone tell me how to differentiate between models.?
Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, so that you can specify the scale factor of the image.  This will use the scale factor of the device's main screen:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
```

This will use the scale factor of the screen containing `cellImage`, if `cellImage` is on a screen:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, cellImage.window.screen.scale);
```

This will hardcode the scale factor:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 2);
```

Comment: didn't understand.. i am thinking about using first one.. will that  do the size 124 x 124 on retina?

Comment: Which part is confusing?  Did you check the documentation of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`?

Comment: [Creating High-Resolution Bitmap Images Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW9)

Comment: thanks... your answer was great.. i am doing this way.. but i just have one doubt ..since i don't have retina device to check `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);`  will give me 124 x 124 image on iPhone 4 and 4s in my above code.. i am using it.. but anyway to check?

Comment: Yes, it will do what you want. You can check it by putting the simulator in Retina mode.