# Why when I add add a UIImage on top of another UIImage for a new image does the added image shrink?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics

I'm trying to add a video player icon on top of a thumbnail of a video.

I get the image from the YouTube API, then crop it to be square, then resize it to be the proper size. I then add my player icon image on top of it.

The problem lies in the fact that the player icon is much smaller than it should be on the thumbnail (it's 28x28pt when on screen it's much smaller). See in the below image where I added it to the cell to show the size it should be, versus the thumbnail size:

[image]

I crop it to a square with this method:

```
/**
 * Given a UIImage, return it with a square aspect ratio (via cropping, not smushing).
 */
- (UIImage *)createSquareVersionOfImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGFloat originalWidth = image.size.width;
    CGFloat originalHeight = image.size.height;

    float smallestDimension = fminf(originalWidth, originalHeight);

    // Determine the offset needed to crop the center of the image out.
    CGFloat xOffsetToBeCentered = (originalWidth - smallestDimension) / 2;
    CGFloat yOffsetToBeCentered = (originalHeight - smallestDimension) / 2;

    // Create the square, making sure the position and dimensions are set appropriately for retina displays.
    CGRect square = CGRectMake(xOffsetToBeCentered * image.scale, yOffsetToBeCentered * image.scale, smallestDimension * image.scale, smallestDimension *image.scale);
    CGImageRef squareImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], square);

    UIImage *squareImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:squareImageRef scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(squareImageRef);

    return squareImage;
}
```

Resize it with this method:

```
/**
 * Resize the given UIImage to a new size and return the newly resized image.
 */
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

And add it on top of the other image with this method:

```
/**
 * Adds a UIImage on top of another UIImage and returns the result. The top image is centered.
 */
- (UIImage *)addImage:(UIImage *)additionalImage toImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImage.size);
    [backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height)];
    [additionalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake((backgroundImage.size.width - additionalImage.size.width) / 2, (backgroundImage.size.height - additionalImage.size.height) / 2, additionalImage.size.width, additionalImage.size.height)];

    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resultingImage;
}
```

And this is how it is implemented:

```
UIImage *squareThumbnail = [self resizeImage:[self createSquareVersionOfImage:responseObject] toSize:CGSizeMake(110.0, 110.0)];
UIImage *playerIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"video-thumbnail-overlay"];
UIImage *squareThumbnailWithPlayerIcon = [self addImage:playerIcon toImage:squareThumbnail];
```

But in the end, the icon is always too small. The sizing things confuse me when working with images, as I'm used to it figuring out retina screen related things automatically, and for example in the above code block, I'm not sure why I set it to `110.0, 110.0` as it's a 55x55 UIImageView and I thought it scales automatically (but if I put it to 55 it's stretched terribly).

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I recommend compositing images with UIViews instead of baking a UIImage from scratch. While your approach won't cause much of an issue with a small number of images, when you want to display 20 or 100 you might find that performance, particularly scrolling, takes a hit.

Comment: I can't do UIViews as it needs to be saved to Core Data. But I guess I could save them separately. So building a UIView of the two images would be better on performance? Would the same apply to adding the second UIImage as a subview of the first UIImageView?

Comment: I don't know all the specifics of your situation. That being said, having implemented something very similar I found that trying to do a lot of preprocessing of images can get pretty gnarly, especially if you decide to change the graphics or design. The operations you have listed can all be handled very smoothly by core graphics and UIKit. The only preprocessing I ever did was ensuring that oversized images where resized down. (For instance, I as getting a 4096x4096 image which thrashed older ipads when I tried to display it.) UIImageViews will handle what you are looking to do pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have to put 110 in your resizeImage call is because you are creating a CGGraphics context with a scale of 1.0.  The graphics context for views in a view hierarchy on retina displays have a scale of 2.0 (provided you did nothing to scale anything else).

I believe that new UIImage that you create is now a "normal" image (Sorry I can't remember the technical term).  It is not an @2x image.  So its size that you will get when you ask for size will not scale for @2x.

Comment: I have the @2x in the project. How do I make it respect that?

Answer (score 0):

Note this answer:
[UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext retina resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274234/uigraphicsgetimagefromcurrentimagecontext-retina-resolutions)

I haven't tested this, but it *should* work. If it doesn't it should at least be more straightforward to debug.

```
//images should be passed in with their original scales
-(UIImage*)compositedImageWithSize:(CGSize)newSize bg:(UIImage*)backgroundImage fgImage:(UIImage*)foregroundImage{
    //match the scale of screen.
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, scale);
    //instead of resizing the image ahead of time, we just draw it into the context at the appropriate size. The context will clip the image.
    CGRect aspectFillRect = CGRectZero;

    if(newSize.width/newSize.height > backgroundImage.size.width/backgroundImage.size.height){
        aspectFillRect.y = 0;
        aspectFillRect.height = newSize.height;
        CGFloat scaledWidth = (newSize.height / backgroundImage.size.height) * newSize.width;
        aspectFillRect.x = (newSize.width - scaledWidth)/2.0;
        aspectFillRect.width = scaledWidth;
    }else{
        aspectFillRect.x = 0;
        aspectFillRect.width = newSize.width;
        CGFloat scaledHeight = (newSize.width / backgroundImage.size.width) * newSize.height;
        aspectFillRect.y = (newSize.height - scaledHeight)/2.0;
        aspectFillRect.height = scaledHeight;
    }

    [backgroundImage drawInRect:aspectFillRect];

    //pass in the 2x image for the fg image so it provides a better resolution
    [foregroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake((newSize.width - additionalImage.size.width) / 2, (newSize.height - additionalImage.size.height) / 2, additionalImage.size.width, additionalImage.size.height)];

    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resultingImage;
}
```

You would skip all those methods you were calling before and do:

```
UIImage *playerIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"video-thumbnail-overlay"];
//pass in the non-retina scale of the image
UIImage *result = [self compositedImageWithSize:CGSizeMake(55.0, 55.0) 
                                             bg:responseObject 
                                             fg:playerIcon];
```

Hope this helps!