# Why UIImageJPEGRepresentation and UIImagePNGRepresentation increase data size?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Doing a image scaling to have image limit in 320x480, so `w` <= 320 and `h` <= 640. But after conversion to data and back conversion to image I get a twice as big image as it was originally. Why? How can I avoid? Should use 160x320 size to get the required size?

```
let s = CGSize(width: w, height: h)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(s, false, 0.0);
image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: w, height: h))
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

let data2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage!, 1.0)!
let image3 = UIImage(data: data2)
```

---

> (lldb) po newImage!.size ▿ (320.0, 213.5)
>     - width : 320.0
>     - height : 213.5
>
> (lldb) po image3!.size ▿ (640.0, 427.0)
>     - width : 640.0
>     - height : 427.0

Comment: Check scale property on both images. I think you will see 2 on first and 1 on second.

Comment: Right, 2, and 1. What to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274234/uigraphicsgetimagefromcurrentimagecontext-retina-resolutions ?

Comment: Try UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(s, false, image.scale);